# How to build json data as formdata in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

How to send the below json as form data ? Tried JSON.stringify and its not working.

```
{
   name: 'starwars',
   year: 1977,
   data: [{ 
    'id': 'c5f6d301-328e-4167-8e13-504afb9a030e', 
    'item': 'bc4db36e-9e7c-478d-93a2-d4be32dacec1', 
    'qty': '1' 
  },
  { 
    'id': 'c5f6d301-328e-4167-8e13-504afb9a030e', 
    'item': 'bc4db36e-9e7c-478d-93a2-d4be32dacec1', 
    'qty': '1' 
  },
 ],
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? anyway I think you have to do json.parse() and pass it the json you've posted up here

Comment: [Angular has a whole guide about that](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Answer (score 2):

```
    var jsonData = {
   name: 'starwars',
   year: 1977,
   data: [{ 
    'id': 'c5f6d301-328e-4167-8e13-504afb9a030e', 
    'item': 'bc4db36e-9e7c-478d-93a2-d4be32dacec1', 
    'qty': '1' 
  },
  { 
    'id': 'c5f6d301-328e-4167-8e13-504afb9a030e', 
    'item': 'bc4db36e-9e7c-478d-93a2-d4be32dacec1', 
    'qty': '1' 
  },
 ],
};
var formData = new FormData();
Object.keys(jsonData).forEach((key)=>{formData.append(key,jsonData[key])});
```

Hope you are asking this. Now you can post the formData to your Rest Api.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http'
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'

@Injectable()
export class YifyMoviesProvider {
    constructor(public http: Http) {

    }
    postData(): Observable < any > {
        let jsonData = {
            name: 'starwars',
            year: 1977,
            data: [{
                    'id': 'c5f6d301-328e-4167-8e13-504afb9a030e',
                    'item': 'bc4db36e-9e7c-478d-93a2-d4be32dacec1',
                    'qty': '1'
                },
                {
                    'id': 'c5f6d301-328e-4167-8e13-504afb9a030e',
                    'item': 'bc4db36e-9e7c-478d-93a2-d4be32dacec1',
                    'qty': '1'
                },
            ],
        };
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json' })
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        })
        let body = new URLSearchParams()
        body.set('mydata', JSON.stringify(jsonData))
        return this.http.post(`yourip`, body, options).
        map(res => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status))
        })
    }
}
```

Incase if you want to post the json data to Rest api as form data this would work in angular 4!

Comment: Please, edit the answer in order to post a [complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). External links are deprecated because they will probably die making the answer meaningless for future users. Think about including all the code in the answer while explaining it to the PO.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var jsonData = {
   'name': 'starwars1',
   'year': 1977,
   'data': [{ 
    'id': 'c5f6d301328416e', 
    'item': 'bc4db36e-9e7c-478d-93a2-d4be32dacec1', 
    'qty': '1' 
  },
  { 
    'id': 'c5f6d301-328e-4167-8e13-504afb9a030e', 
    'item': 'bc4db36e-9e7c-478d-93a2-d4be32dacec1', 
    'qty': '1' 
  },
 ],
};
```